# strlen() crashes when I call it

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple piece of code that merges two strings together in even and odd indexes.

This is the code

```
void two_strings(char a[], char b[]) {
    int counta = 0, countb = 0;
    int lena = strlen(a); 
    int lenb = strlen(b);
    int lenab = lena + lenb;
    char ans[lenab];
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(ans); i++) {
        if(i%2 == 0) {
            ans[i] = a[counta];
            counta++;
        }
        else {
            ans[i] = b[countb];
            countb++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", ans);
}
```

This is the main:

```
int main() {   
    char a[] = "hello";
    char b[] = "bye";
    two_strings(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled it with -Wall and didn't get any warnings or errors, and I have tried it also with long instead of int just to check if that was the issue. when I run the code it doesn't get past the first strlen(a)

Comment: `i<strlen(ans)` should not be the condition in that for-loop. That array has no null-terminated string in it, so invoking `strlen` invokes *undefined behavior*.  And fyi, you're also not terminating your string anyway, and you don't have the extra slot to do so even if you tried.

Comment: There's no data in `ans` variable.

Comment: Also, consider using a function to concatenate strings such as `strncat()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, as soon as I removed i<strlen(ans) it worked!

Comment: What do you expect the output to be with "hello" and "bye" as input? It will currently read past the end of the shorter string.

Comment: That isn't the only problem. What I mentioned about termination is important. You also assume both strings have at-most-one char length difference between them, which your sample data does not comply with.

Comment: @Anic17 — don't recommend `strncat()` to beginners. It has an inscrutable interface and is easy to misuse.  Did you know that `strncat(buffer, very_long_string, sizeof(buffer))` is an automatic buffer overflow if the long string is longer than the space left in the buffer?  Even if buffer is currently holding an empty string?

Comment: regardingt: ` char ans[lenab];
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(ans); i++) {`   the array: `ans[]` is declared but does not contain anything but trash, so cannot use `strlen()` without causing undefined behavior

Answer (score 4):

[Strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) in C are defined as a sequence of non-null bytes followed by a terminating null byte (`'\0'`).

The following are equivalent strings

```
char one[] = "hello";
char two[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

Both of these would have a *string length* of `5`, and occupy `6` bytes of memory.

String handling functions in the Standard Library expect this null-terminating byte, and you will invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by passing a non-null-terminated array to them. `strlen` and `printf` (with `%s`) are examples of these kinds of functions.

In your `two_strings` function you are not allocating enough memory to store the null-terminating byte. You also make no attempt to place this null-terminating byte in the array.

Allocate an additional byte for the null-terminating byte, and do not attempt to take the string length of an uninitialized array.

```
void two_strings(char a[], char b[]) {
    /* ... */

    size_t length = strlen(a) + strlen(b);
    char string[length + 1];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        /* ... */
    }

    string[length] = '\0';

    /* ... */
}
```

Also note that [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is the correct type to use when dealing with memory indexing, and is the type returned by `strlen`.

---

As for your algorithm, in the event where your input strings differ in length you will attempt to continue indexing one of the strings after you have already reached its end.

You will either want to: only take the smaller string's length of characters from the larger string, stopping when the smaller string has been exhausted; or, append the remaining characters of the larger string to the result after the smaller string has been exhausted.

A quick example of the second approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void zip_strings(const char *a, const char *b) {    
    size_t combined_length = strlen(a) + strlen(b);
    char joined_string[combined_length + 1];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < combined_length; i++) {
        const char **src = i & 1 ? &b : &a;

        if (!**src)
            src = &a;
        if (!**src)
            src = &b;

        joined_string[i] = *((*src)++);
    }
    
    joined_string[combined_length] = '\0';

    puts(joined_string);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 2)
        zip_strings(argv[1], argv[2]);    
}
```

```
./a.out hello computer
hceolmlpouter
```